# Play Framework - Interfaces for methods that use Promise.failure(exception)

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0, java-8

**Background**

Java interfaces specify the contract between the caller and callee sides of development. For example:

```
public interface SomeContainer<T> {
    public boolean add(T value) throws SomeException;
}
```

The above method must return either a boolean or throw the given exception, and nothing else.

**Problem Description**

How can I do the same for a Play Promise-based method? A promise does not "throw" an exception; rather, a promises executes Promise.failure(ExceptionHere). Hence, my interface doesn't "throw" anything:

```
public interface SomeContainer<T> {
    public Promise<boolean> add(T value);
}
```

However, the above definition does not prevent the implementating class from executing Promise.failure()--not a very good interface definition.

One possibility is to return a "Result" object which can contain the boolean or one of several allowed exceptions. However, this seems hackish, and still does not prevent the implementing code from calling Promise.failure() anyway.

**Question**

How does one write an effective Play Promise-based interface, where all return values and all acceptable exceptions are specified and nothing else is allowed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're describing is a fundamental limitation of exceptions - their specification only works when they are thrown directly from a method.  The problem is not specific to promises, it manifests itself all over the place, anytime you package execution of something up into a generic interface, which is especially pertinent when using lambdas.  Consider doing a `List.forEach`, that doesn't throw an exception, but typically you will pass a lambda to it (which will implement java.util.function.Function), what if that lambda throws an exception?  The answer is, it can't, unless it's an unchecked exception, and then there's no way to know statically that that exception will be thrown through to the caller of `forEach`.

The only real answer is don't use exceptions.  If you talk to a functional programming purist, they will say never, ever use exceptions, instead of exceptions you should use a disjoint type.  Play's Java API actually provides such a type, it's `play.libs.F.Either`.  Convention is that the left should be the error, and the right the value.  That said, Play's either type is quite limited, and doesn't compose very well with itself or other things.  The either type provided by the [Functional Java](http://www.functionaljava.org/) library is much more complete, and composes well.  If you value being as strict as possible about type safety, in particular with exceptions, then this is probably the library for you, even without using promises, encoding errors into return types offers better type safety than exceptions, and makes it very straight forward to compose and reuse error handling.  And if that sounds like a good option to you, then you should also consider using a language with stronger typing than Java, eg Scala.

If you're like me though and are little more pragmatic about things, then you'll use a hybrid approach.  In some cases, it's really important for the caller to explicitly handle errors, in which case, they should be encoded in the types, an example of this is form validation, you don't just want to throw an error, you want to handle it by rendering a page with multiple meaningful error messages in it - this is a perfect example of where strongly typed error handling really shines, you can return a list of errors, one for each field that had a problem in a form, but you can't throw a list of exceptions.  In other cases, errors really are exceptional things that don't usually have a specific handling strategy, instead they should be left to a general catch all high up in the stack to handle generically.  For example, if the database is down, that's not something that you can usually recover from.  In these cases, you lose nothing by throwing unchecked exceptions and letting the generic error handling do its thing.

Comment: Thanks James. I use a hybrid approach as well. The core database methods propagate the error for flexibility; higher level methods may ignore it and just return error. I am no Java expert and hoped there might be a cleaner way to do it, but I guess the Either type will have to do!